# Long-time running task and ignoring subsequent doGet() calls

Tags: java, servlets

I have a simple servlet that can return a video file to the client. What I want to do is to download the file from a URL onto my server and then send that newly downloaded file to the client. My problem is the entrance point of the servlet is inside the doGet() method where the client requests the file. I want to download the file once and use it as a static file. However, because I call the download function inside my doGet(), while the client tries to get the file it keeps repeating everything that happen inside doGet() and my file keeps being overwritten. It really slows down the entire process. Is there anyway I can just call my download function once?

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
  answerRequest(request, response); 
}
...

public void answerRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)              
               throws IOException{
  String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();

  URL newURL = "fixed URL content";
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) newURL.openConnection();


  sendFile(connection,  request, response); 
}

...

public void sendFile(HttpURLConnection connection, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
  InputStream input = null;
  FileOutputStream output = null;


 File videoFile = new File("path-to-file");
 input = connection.getInputStream();
 output = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
 Utility.download(input, output,  0, connection.getContentLength()); //this is where the file is downloaded onto my server)


 connection.disconnect();
 close(output);
 close(input);

 //this is where the file is sent back to client
 Utility.sendFile(videoFile, response, request,true);
...
}
```

So as you can see, all of those function happen every time doGet() happen. But I only want the Utility.download() to execute once. How would I do that?

Comment: The doGet is there to respond to every GET request that gets through to it. You need to have a flag somewhere or a Thread to handle the file until it's completed. Additionaly, you could add some basic caching mecanism in case another user wishes to download the same file.

Comment: Thanks. You're completely right.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean flag to Session variable. For example, when the do get is executed for the first Time:

```
boolean started = true;
```

Then right before you call Utility.sendFile() check whether the boolean flag is true or false and run the method accordingly.

Comment: ohhhhh, that makes total sense. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.